# Slowness of node/deno postgres client on mac

Tags: node.js, postgresql, macos, v8, deno

I have encountered peculiar slowness on mac, when using node-postgres or deno-postgres. I have a very simple table with two columns, and when I execute query `select * from table` it happens very very slowly. I have also tried selecting directly with SQL client and it is very fast.

So to be precise - the table has 60 entries. two columns. on the remote postgres server (12.2)

I have the following three scripts.

```
#node v13.12.0

const { Client } = require('pg')

const client = new Client({
  user: 'u',
  host: 'address',
  database: 'db',
  password: 'pw',
  port: 5432,
})

client.connect()

const start = Date.now();

client.query('SELECT * from unit', (err, res) => {
  const ms = Date.now() - start;
  console.log(`db call ${ms}`);
  
  console.log(res.rows.length);
  
  client.end()
})
```

```
#deno 1.1.2
#v8 8.5.216
#typescript 3.9.2

import { Client } from "https://deno.land/x/postgres@v0.4.2/mod.ts";

const client = new Client({
  user: "u",
  database: "db",
  hostname: "addr",
  password: "pw",
  port: 5432,
});

await client.connect();

const start = Date.now();

const dataset = await client.query("SELECT * FROM unit");
const ms = Date.now() - start;
console.log(`db call ${ms}`);
console.log(dataset.rowsOfObjects().length)
```

```
#python 3.7.7

import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime
#try:
connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "u",
                                password = "p",
                                host = "addr",
                                port = "5432",
                                database = "db")

cursor = connection.cursor()
a = datetime.now()
cursor.execute("select * from unit");
records = cursor.fetchall()    
b = datetime.now()
c = b - a 

print(len(records))
print(c.total_seconds() * 1000)
```

and when I execute all three scripts on my macos (10.15.5) I get the following results:

"select * from unit" (60 records)

```
node   ~16'000ms
deno   ~16'000ms 
python    ~240ms
```

when I execute "select * from unit limit 5"

```
node      ~480ms
deno      ~110ms
python    ~220ms
```

when I execute "select * from unit" on the same ubuntu server where postgres is installed then all 3 scripts execute in around 10ms.

I have enabled timing and full logging in the postgres server, and I see that I can see that queries in *all* the above situations have executed in below one milisecond, around ~0.600ms

At this point, I have feeling that fault lies into intersection of node/deno and my macos, which could probably be v8. or something else that deno and node share.

So, what could it be?

p.s I also tried node profiler and I see this:

```
[Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
      0    0.0%    0.0%  JavaScript
    116   84.7%   99.1%  C++
     22   16.1%   18.8%  GC
     20   14.6%          Shared libraries
      1    0.7%          Unaccounted

 [C++ entry points]:
   ticks    cpp   total   name
     45   54.9%   32.8%  T __ZN2v88internal32Builtin_DatePrototypeSetUTCHoursEiPmPNS0_7IsolateE
     36   43.9%   26.3%  T __ZN2v88internal21Builtin_HandleApiCallEiPmPNS0_7IsolateE
      1    1.2%    0.7%  T __ZN2v88internal23Builtin_DateConstructorEiPmPNS0_7IsolateE
```

but I have no idea what that might mean.

Comment: which region you are trying and from which region your database is?

Comment: it is not aws. or what do you mean region? do you think network could be the issue if python script is not affected?

Comment: Can you try if using a connection pool changes anything in Node: https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling ?

Comment: just checked all the scripts again - looks like effect has disappeared completely. So I guess it was something related to my macos environment that was causing it, and it is now gone. Will check pooling if issue comes back again. Though not sure how pooling can help if only one connection is in play for one query.

Comment: and now issue is back. it feels like it depends on time of the day somehow :/

Comment: tried with pool for node as suggested, no differences in the outcome

Comment: tried on other mac/windows envireonment ?

Comment: no, don't have any at hand. Though I wouldn't be surprised a slightest if it would work perfectly elsewhere. I mean it sometimes _does_ work fast on my mac too, just rarely. I still don't get it :/

Comment: Can you try with disabled Set date & time automatically on OSX?

Comment: unfortunately - no difference. but I will keep settings off, maybe it will make difference later.

Comment: This smells like a dns lookup timeout.

Comment: I think the `limit 5` benchmark is the most telling. If the only difference between 16s and ~400ms is the limit on the query, some operation that is occurring per-row is evidently taking an inordinate amount of time. The node profiling results suggest the time is spent in C, most notably Date.prototype.setUTCHours. Have you tried re-compiling your node / deno version or installing a slightly newer version? Does indeed seem like an issue between your mac and v8, which could be the result of how it was compiled.

Comment: yeah, originally I had node 13.x, I also tried with 12.x LTS and with latest 14.x - no difference. Each of them also has different v8 versions, so issue could be in my mac but somehow how can it be only v8 specific and how to test for it, no idea :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I finally figured it out.

As nothing was working I decided to move my API to the remote server instead of running it locally, started it up, and was pleased to see instant communication between API and database... only to see exactly the same slowness on the frontend running on my machine.

And this is when it dawned on me - this is some sort of traffic shaping from my internet provider. I turned on VPN and everything started working as expected immediately.

No wonder I couldn't understand why it was getting stuck. The issue was way down the stack, this will be a lesson for me - always have to think outside the box that is a computer itself.

this explains why it was sometimes working normally. However, it doesn't explain why this issue never affected python script - maybe it was communicating with the Postgres server in a little bit different manner that didn't trigger the provider's filter. Who knows.